# Trying to list all users belong to this project model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The user and project_model have a habtm association, and this is part of an index of project_models, and each one is meant to have a list of project_models.users being displayed. As simple as this is, for some reason it keeps throwing an error:

Edit: Forgot to mention that each user has a lot of parts to them, one of them being their email, which I'm trying to display in list.

```
     @members = project_model.users.all
   <% @members.each do |member| %>
    <%= member.email %>
    <% end %>
```

It tells me .each is an undefined method for nil:NilClass. I don't understand what I did wrong. Is the join table set up wrong?

```
  class CreateJoinTableProjectModelUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
   create_join_table :users, :project_models do |t|
     # t.index [:user_id, :project_model_id]
     # t.index [:project_model_id, :user_id]
    end
   end
  end
```

Or is it something else? I'm new to Rails (first time having to use it) so please forgive me if the questions are bit low level.

Comment: this can't be answered properly without controller method. Where you declare your @members? And where do you invoke this instance? Are you sure that controller action matches view file?

Comment: Well it's being declared within the view since all project_models are stored within @project_models in the controller, but the project_model.users is meant to be specific to each one so I thought doing that in the controller wouldn't work. Is it not possible to declare things in the view because I thought we could? I'm pretty sure I've seen code where people have declared them outside the controllers?

Comment: if it is `@project_models` in controller, why it is called `project_models` in view? It is possible, but this violates Rails logic.

Comment: I forgot to mention this is in a 'do' loop where  @project_models.each do |project_model|

Comment: update with ALL related code if issue still unsolved

Comment: Um, I'm not sure what that means...

Answer (score 1):

To explain more about this error whenever you encounter

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

You're calling the `each` method on something(@members) which is nil. This means it hasn't been defined in the controller. Since it wasn't defined, you get an `undefined method` error.

It's a good idea to check whenever you call an instance variable in your view that it is defined in your controller as well.

It's also possible to get this error if you call a private method in your controller.

Comment: When I define it in the controller, do I simply put in members by itself in the controller? Or members = etc...

Because each project_model needs to give its own member list, or are you saying I should make a members = users.all and have it where each project model checks to see if a member belongs to its project_models.users and then displays that?
Also, when I looked around at other posts and guides I've seen a lot of these instance variables being declared here as well?